# Is it possible to host Nuget packages and symbols on the same server?

Tags: nuget-server

I have private Nuget server and recently I decided to add symbol packages.
Unfortunately after I add `symbols.nupkg` files, server started to 
return following error:

```
A single resource was expected for the result, but multiple resources were found.
```

and Nuget Package Explorer shows doubled packages (with same name and version).
Do symbols packages need their own server, or I did something wrong?

Comment: You can try publishing symbols with a different ID on the same sever. From http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package symbols are generally published to a different source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) is both a NuGet and Symbol Server; to publish both to the same feed, you simply put the symbols in the same package, and publish. The free version supports this as well.

(disclaimer: I work for Inedo)